# Setting itemTextAppearance for Android NavigationView gives a "bold" text style

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-support-design

I have 4 text style defined between my designer and my Android app.

I had to add a Navigation Drawer today and give the nav drawer menu items a style that we already have set. The issue is that when I add a style it shows the text looking like it's bold. Does anyone see any issues with my code?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/offWhite"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/custom_nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_menu_item_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_drawer"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Header4" <!--The issue -->
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is what Header4 is defined as

```
<style name="Header4">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">.06</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is this only on the preview or also in the app while runing on a device or emulator?

Answer (score 1):

**Try :**

In your dimen.xml you can put:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">16sp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what might be the issue, but try to change the font or set the text style to "normal".